# Python2.5, smtplib and KeyError

Tags: python, smtplib, esxi, busybox

I'm trying to write a python script for BusyBox on ESXi with mail functionality. It runs Python 2.5 with some libraries missing (i.e. the smtplib). I downloaded Python2.5 sources and copied the lib-folder to ESXi. Now I am trying to import the smtplib via "import lib.smtplib" but Python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/pysexi/lib/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
 import email.Utils
 File "/pysexi/lib/email/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
 setattr(sys.modules['email'], _name, importer)
KeyError: 'email'
```

I'm stuck. So every help and every thought is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to install generic applications on an appliance or custom OS is always fun.

Just a guess, but it may be that the email lib is a compiled C module - i.e. not pure python.

I would try use libraries that are as completely python with no compiled code - I don't know if there are pure python versions of the libraries.

The option is to try to track down what OS version that ESXi is based on and then use the matching python version from that OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about BusyBox or ESXi - therefore this may be more of a suggestion than an answer, but you might consider using a email service that supports an HTTP or RESTful API - such as  [MailGun](http://documentation.mailgun.net/wrappers.html#python).  They have a free plan for up to 200 emails a day, so it might not cost you anything.

Again, this way be more of a suggestion or a plan "B" (if no one can help you with this specific problem)